# Graph velocity and distance from calculus functions in Python

Tags: python, calculus

[image]

Is there an more code-light way I could have implemented graphing the following piece-wise functions in the calculus problem more easily? In my approach, I used matplotlib and just combined the graphs into two main graphs to show the discontinuity.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def v(time_range):
    velocity_val = []
    for i in time_range:
        if i < .2:
            velocity_val.append(20)
        elif i > .2:
            velocity_val.append(0)
    return velocity_val

def f(time_range):
    distance_val = []
    for i in time_range:
        if i <= .2:
            distance_val.append(20*i)
        if i >= .2:
            distance_val.append(4)
    return distance_val

def time_vals(time_range):
    decimal = 100
    time_val = []
    for i in time_range:
        num = i / decimal
        time_val.append(num)
    return time_val

#convert time into decimal
time_range_1 = range(1,20,1)
time_range_2 = range(21,40,1)
t_1 = time_vals(time_range_1)
t_2 = time_vals(time_range_2)

#get x, y for plot
v_1 = v(t_1)
v_2 = v(t_2)
f_1 = f(t_1)
f_2 = f(t_2)

#plot values into two graphs.
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t_1, v_1)
plt.plot(t_2, v_2)
plt.title(' Problem 9')
plt.ylabel('Velocity')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t_1, f_1)
plt.plot(t_2, f_2)
plt.xlabel('time (t)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity');
```

Comment: Why is the velocity before the crash zero and afterwards non-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `np.where` to assign your `v(t)` and `f(t)` depending on your the conditions. You don't need any for loops. Vectorized approaches make your code much neat and short. In `np.where`, you first check the condition and then the first value after the condition is assigned to the indices where the condition holds `True` and the second value is assigned to the indices where the condition holds `False`.

Below is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialise time
t_1 = np.arange(1,20,1)/100
t_2 = np.arange(21,40,1)/100

# Compute v(t)
v_1 = np.where(t_1<0.2, 20, 0)
v_2 = np.where(t_2<0.2, 20, 0)

# Compute f(t)
f_1 = np.where(t_1<=0.2, 20*t_1, 4)
f_2 = np.where(t_2<=0.2, 20*t_2, 4)

# Plotting as you are doing
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` to vectorize your code

Maybe something like:

```
# Define time steps
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
# Build v
v = np.empty_like(t)
v[.2 < t] = 20
v[.2 >= t] = 0
# Build f
f = np.empty_like(t)
f[t < 0.2] = 20 * t[t < 0.2]
f[t >= 0.2] = 4
# Plot
plt.plot(t, v)
plt.plot(t, d)
```

Another way of building `v` and `f` is by using `np.piecewise`:

```
v = np.piecewise(t, [.2 < t, .2 >= t], [20, 0])
f = np.piecewise(t, [t <= .2, t > .2], [lambda x: 20 * x, 4])
```

I think `np.piecewise` is not very readable, but it definitely saves some lines of code